# Check if any of multiple values exist in an array in Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, pattern-matching

Checking if one value exists in an array is pretty trivial. For example, the following will return true.

```
SELECT 'hello' = ANY(ARRAY['hello', 'bees'])
```

But what if I wanted to check if any of multiple values exist in an array? For example, I want to return true if 'hello' OR 'bye' exists in an array. I want to do something like

```
SELECT ['hello', 'bye'] = ANY(ARRAY['hello', 'bees'])
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Edit:

I'm also looking to figure out how I can check if any of multiple values exist in an array where the multiple values have common prefixes.

For example, if I want to return true if the array contains any element with the prefix of 'hello'. So I basically want something like

```
SELECT ARRAY['hello%'] && ARRAY['helloOTHERSTUFF']
```

to be true.

Comment: `ARRAY['hello', 'bye'] && ARRAY['hello', 'bees']`

Comment: Thanks! What if the multiple values span multiple things with the same prefix? For example I want to match any value in the array that starts with 'hello'. For example, I would want something like `ARRAY['hello'] && ARRAY['helloOTHERSTUFF']` to be true. I'll also edit the original post.

Comment: For something that arbitrary you'll need to use unnest() to turn both arrays into recordsets and then JOIN them as appropriate. You can use array() to turn that back into an array.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to do something similar to an `field_name ILIKE 'hello%'` except for arrays. Is that not possible?

Comment: It is possible if you want to compare a single value with array of patterns (similar to `any` but `like` instead of `=`), but not vise versa. The general pattern for complex comparison of two (or more) arrays is `exists 1 from unnest(<array1>) as t1(x1) join unnest(<array2>) as t2(x2) on (<join condition>)`, where `<join condition>` for your example could be `x1 ilike x2`.

Answer (score 12):

For checking if any of the array elements exists in another array use overlap [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) operator like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1] -- true
```

A check if every array element matches a specific pattern you could use [`unnest(anyarray)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) (to extract array elements) function combined with [LIKE or POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) (to apply pattern matching) and an aggregate [`bool_and(expression)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) - to perform the bitwise AND operator and return one row of output.

**Test case:**

I have put array elements in separate lines to clarify which comparison yields true and which false.

```
SELECT bool_and(array_elements)
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(
    ARRAY[
     'hello', -- compared with LIKE 'hello%' yields true
     'helloSOMething', -- true
     'helloXX', -- true
     'hell', -- false
     'nothing' -- false
    ]) ~~ 'hello%'
  ) foo(array_elements);
```

So if any of the comparison yields false then the `bool_and(array_elements)` will return false.

**Note:** If you need to compare your array against multiple patterns, you could go with POSIX comparison and use `|` which stands for alternative. As an example let's say we want to find out if every element of an array starts with either `hello` or `not` words:

```
SELECT bool_and(array_elements)
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(
    ARRAY[
     'hello', -- true
     'helloSOMething', -- true
     'helloXX', -- true
     'hell', -- false (doesn't start with neither "hello" nor "not")
     'nothing' -- true (starts with not)
    ]) ~ '^hello|not' -- note the use of ~ instead of ~~ as earlier (POSIX vs LIKE)
  ) foo(array_elements);
```

Comment: Note: if dealing with text and one of the ARRAYs is coming from an aggregation, you might need to cast the underlying datum to `text`: `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT tbl.col::text) && ARRAY['x', 'y',..]`